# Laravel 5.5 sessions and CSRF tokens expire on every page refresh, ajax request or open another page

Tags: laravel, session, token, csrf-token

I'm using Laravel 5.5. I can't login because of this problem. Even when I use `Auth::loginUsingId(1);` I can't login. When I refresh the page, I'm not logged in.

When I login with CSRF enabled I get:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.

When I add log url to exception

```
Auth::attempt return true
```

then my code must redirect me to my personal page, but I get redirected to the login page because my personal page is only for authorized users.

i tried everything on this issue from this site and didnt solve problem

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:EbBctSTYXlY8SYiUGXrHLop633hDLvn4DLhH35Gdp2o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=mysiteurl_with_https
SESSION_DOMAIN=site.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=1111111111

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=1200
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

**my config/session.php**

```
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => null,
```

**Update**
today i tried new installation of laravel 5.5 on the same server and i get the same error - token in form changes on every reload page - so is the session

Comment: You put your client secrets dude, hope they are not live

Comment: i changed them)))

Comment: @Kaner we can see them in the edits still. I suggest deleting the whole question and starting over

Comment: @DerekPollard i deleted unusefull info

Comment: it would be nice if someone help me with my problem - i cant fix it the second day